# BackupTransportService Server policy exception

Tags: java, android, backup, android-preferences, android-backup-service

In order to try to stay "up to date" with my apps, I wanted to implement the Backup-Service from Android's Framework.

What I did was add 3 preference files with the SharedPreferenceBackupHelper and Implement my own database backup helper as a form of the FileBackupHelper.

However, when I tried to initiate a backup using the adb shell commands from the documentation, I get following error.

```
10-05 13:16:09.861: E/BackupTransportService(598): Server policy rejection: 
10-05 13:16:09.861: E/BackupTransportService(598): com.google.android.backup.BackupRequestGenerator$PolicyException: server error in app com.sapps.savetodrive: code 7
10-05 13:16:09.861: E/BackupTransportService(598):  at com.google.android.backup.BackupRequestGenerator.parseResponse(BackupRequestGenerator.java:360)
10-05 13:16:09.861: E/BackupTransportService(598):  at com.google.android.backup.BackupTransportService.sendRequestLocked(BackupTransportService.java:849)
10-05 13:16:09.861: E/BackupTransportService(598):  at com.google.android.backup.BackupTransportService.access$600(BackupTransportService.java:78)
10-05 13:16:09.861: E/BackupTransportService(598):  at com.google.android.backup.BackupTransportService$1.finishBackup(BackupTransportService.java:444)
10-05 13:16:09.861: E/BackupTransportService(598):  at com.android.server.BackupManagerService$PerformBackupTask.operationComplete(BackupManagerService.java:2204)
10-05 13:16:09.861: E/BackupTransportService(598):  at com.android.server.BackupManagerService$BackupHandler.handleMessage(BackupManagerService.java:544)
10-05 13:16:09.861: E/BackupTransportService(598):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-05 13:16:09.861: E/BackupTransportService(598):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-05 13:16:09.861: E/BackupTransportService(598):  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

My key is correct, I tried using the debug-signed apk and the normal signed apk, but both throw the same error.

Any idea what's that all about? I am wondering.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution/cause for this?

Comment: Sadly not. I skipped the implementation of it back then. I might try it again at some point (maybe it was a bug in some api and got fixed..)